# Why is the definition of energy density in auxiliary field method consistent with the common one?

Tags: electromagnetism, linear-algebra, dispersion, photonics

In [PRL 104, 087401 (2010)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.087401) ([PDF](https://web.stanford.edu/group/fan/publication/Raman_PRL_104_087401_2010.pdf)), the authors provide an alternative way to formulate dispersive photonic media.
Here I would like to take lossless dielectrics with Lorentz dispersion $\epsilon\left(\omega\right)=1+\frac{\omega_p^2}{-\omega^2+\omega_0^2}$ as an example. I also let $\epsilon_0=\mu_0=1$ for simplicity and modify the notations a little bit to fit in this minimum working model.

Long story short, by adding two effective fields $\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{V}$, such that $-i\omega \mathbf{V} =\omega_{p}^{2}\mathbf{E}-\omega_{0}^{2} \mathbf{P}$ and $-i\omega \textbf{P}=\textbf{V}$, Maxwell's equations with dispersive relations are expressed as a generalized eigen-value problem.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix} 
  0 & i \nabla \times & 0 & -i \\
-i \nabla \times & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & +i \frac{\omega_{0}^{2}}{\omega_{p}^{2}} \\
+i & 0 & -i \frac{\omega_{0}^{2}}{\omega_{p}^{2}} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{E} \\ \textbf{H} \\ \textbf{P} \\ \textbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}
=\omega
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\omega_0^2}{\omega^2_p} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\omega_p^2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{E} \\ \textbf{H} \\ \textbf{P} \\ \textbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
The energy density is defined as "<bra|material matrix|ket>".
\begin{equation}
    W_1=\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{E} \\ \textbf{H} \\ \textbf{P} \\ \textbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}^\dagger \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\omega_0^2}{\omega^2_p} & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\omega_p^2} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \textbf{E} \\ \textbf{H} \\ \textbf{P} \\ \textbf{V}
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{2}\left(|\textbf{E}|^2+|\textbf{H}|^2+\frac{\omega_0^2}{\omega_p^2}|\textbf{P}|^2+\frac{1}{\omega_p^2}|\textbf{V}|^2\right)
\end{equation}
Meanwhile, the conventional definition of energy density is
\begin{equation}
    W_2=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d(\omega \epsilon)}{d\omega}|\textbf{E}|^2+|\textbf{H}|^2\right)
\end{equation}
Further calculation shows $W_1=W_2$, which is a nice result but confuses me as well, because $W_2$ is based on the narrow-band assumption (meaning the energy in frequency domain is localized within a narrow band), while $W_1$ does not seem to suppose anything.

Why are they consistent? Afterall, why does $W_1=W_2$?